# What would be the best/cleanest way of dealing with nested submodules as dependencies?

Tags: git, dependencies, git-submodules

I am working on a project that has multiple repositories active. In one of these repositories we store common libraries that are needed across all repositories.

Within each repository, we have a RepoName.Adapter csproj which has a portion of the common library as a dependency. The adapter is designed to be used in other repositories to allow communication between the each component of the project.

We have recently made a new repository which requires us to use submodules to call both the common library, and one of these adapter classes in.

[image: Project Folder structure]

I know this can be loaded in by running `git submodule update --init --recursive` and then the 'Nested' common component can be added in as an existing project to solve the dependency issue and allow the solution to build.

However this introduces an issue in having duplicated code within the repository and also makes editing the Common library (if/when necessary) a bit of a headache due to showing up twice in the repository list.

[image: Repository List]

Submodule control can be hard enough in cases. We are potentially looking at publishing the common library into a private NuGet feed once the common library is fully developed/alteration is no longer needed.

I am trying to find a way that will minimise difficulty in working on these solutions, especially when we may need to edit the common library.